# how to receive notification when user turn off notification in APP

Tags: ios, swift

In Android, can receive Notification while message in FCM Notification Data obj when User turn off Notification setting. But in iOS, is it possible to receive Notification when user turn off Notification setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user explicitly turned off the notification for the application, there is no way you can send notification to the user.
A suggestion is when the user is using the application, you can use

```
UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications
```

to check if the remote notifications are enabled / disabled and you can request the user to navigate to settings to enable the same.

Comment: @NeilLin If you find the answer helpful, can you please accept it as answer.

Comment: I wish I can find other answer...,thanks for your help .

Comment: @NeilLin will you please let me know How we can still receive notification in android APP when user manually turned off notification from setting menu?