# Receive Notifications even when my App's notification is turned off by user from Settings

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications

I have a requirement of implementing a silent kind of notification where in if user turn off notification explicitly from settings menu but still receive a notification.

Checking notification is turned off/on is possible and can navigate to settings page where we can ask to user to toggle the button to make it off/on. 
But my requirement is either dynamically on notification which is turned off. I searched a lot but did not find a solution.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502722/how-to-receive-notification-when-user-turn-off-notification-in-app) link user who asked a question says that we can receive in android but not in iOS. As per my knowledge we can't because what is the use of giving option(from settings menu turn off) to user.

Will anyone let me know whether it is possible!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a reason for turning off annoying notifications you know...

Comment: yes I know. But i am building application for parental control app for kids. so even though kid turns off notification, parent should have a control.